# Can't delete DNS settings added as a configuration profile

Tags: dns, configuration-profiles

I added the wrong DNS Settings as a configuration profile and would love to delete it. I can't do it from Filters & Proxies, and for some strange reason, it isn't showing in the profile section as, well. How can I delete it through terminal on in any other way?

Edit: It was a certificate downloaded and created by https://apple.nextdns.io but with the wrong NextDNS profile number. It is installed and activated, and I can turn it on and off in Filters & Proxies. It works, and it changes my DNS settings.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us a bit more information?

Theoretically,  you could start by `networksetup -getdns "Wi-Fi"`
Or copy and paste the actual configuration profile, edit the config file itself using either plistbuddy, vim, nvim or text edit - However, i must say from the information which you've provided, it seems as if the Configuration Profile has not yet been, either: Activated or Installed.

Please check again and furnish us with some more info.

If you're looking for a quick and dirty way to reset all network settings try  listing all NetworkInterface Files and Airport Related files within the `/Library/Preferences` directory.

ie)
`sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/NetworkInterfaces* &&\  sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.airport*`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added more details to the original question.